# Puppeteer to fill username password details on the alert dialog

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer, alert

I am using puppeteer for taking screenshots for some sites periodically. These sites require login before entering which i did for the few sites where html content is loaded by examining the input name, class elements but i came across one site where html content is not loaded and i am shown an alert box for entering username and password. I am attaching image here on the screen.

[image: Site having alert box for entering username and passowrd]

Can anyone please guide me how to enter username password details on the alert box using puppeteer?

I tried using page.authenticate method of puppeteer but it didn't work for me.

`await page.authenticate({ username, password, });`

I am unable to find input username and password elements otherwise i would have used the following:-

```
 const usernameInput = await page.$('input[name="username"]');
  const passwordInput = await page.$('input[name="password"]');
  const loginButton = await page.$("button.tb-button-login");
await usernameInput.type(username);
    await passwordInput.type(password);
    await loginButton.click();
```